# How to compute the Hessian matrix in the robustified Gauss-Newton method for optimization

Tags: slam, estimation

When robustifying the Gauss-Newton method used to find a local minima of a squared error function expressed by:
$$f(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{2}\Delta\mathbf{z}(\mathbf{x})^T\Delta\mathbf{z}(\mathbf{x})$$,
as explained in works like [Bundle adjustment: A Modern Synthesis](https://lear.inrialpes.fr/pubs/2000/TMHF00/Triggs-va99.pdf#page=17) (page 17), we have to introduce a strong nonlinearity into this cost function, which is denoted by $\rho(\cdot)$ (it can be e.g. the [Huber loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss)).

Thereby to reduce the influence of outliers, we are no longer interested in minimizing $f(\mathbf{x})$, but the *robustified* version of it: $\rho(f(\mathbf{x}))$. Hence, the gradient vector ($\mathbf{g}$) and the *approximate* Hessian matrix ($\mathbf{H}$) are given by:

$$
\mathbf{g} = \rho'\mathbf{J}^T\Delta\mathbf{z},\quad\quad \mathbf{H} \approx \mathbf{J}^T(\rho'\,\mathbf{I} + 2\rho''\Delta\mathbf{z} (\Delta\mathbf{z})^T)\mathbf{J}
$$
Where $\rho'$ and $\rho''$ are the first and second derivatives of $\rho(f(\mathbf{x}))$ w.r.t $f(\mathbf{x})$. And $\mathbf{J}$ is the jacobian matrix given by: $\mathbf{J} = \partial \Delta\mathbf{z}/\partial \mathbf{x}$.

---

Given this, what I don't understand is how this approximation of the Hessian matrix is computed.

My attempt to reach it, is the following:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{H} &= \frac{\partial^2\rho(f(\mathbf{x}))}{\partial \mathbf{x}^2} = \frac{\partial\rho(f(\mathbf{x}))}{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}\frac{\partial^2 f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}^2} + \frac{\partial^2\rho(f(\mathbf{x}))}{\partial f(\mathbf{x})^2}\left(\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\right)^2 && \text{By applying chain rule}
\end{align}
$$
Where:
$$\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial\rho(f(\mathbf{x}))}{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}\frac{\partial^2 f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}^2} \approx \rho'\mathbf{J}^T\mathbf{J}\quad\leftrightarrow\quad\text{Gauss-Newton approximation}\\
\\
&\frac{\partial^2\rho(f(\mathbf{x}))}{\partial f(\mathbf{x})^2}\left(\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\right)^2 = \rho''\,\mathbf{J}^T\Delta\mathbf{z} (\Delta\mathbf{z})^T\mathbf{J}
\end{align}
$$
Thereby I am getting an approximated Hessian where the second term is not multplied by 2:
$$ 
\mathbf{H}_{\text{attempt}} \approx \mathbf{J}^T(\rho'\,\mathbf{I} + \rho''\Delta\mathbf{z} (\Delta\mathbf{z})^T)\mathbf{J} \neq \mathbf{J}^T(\rho'\,\mathbf{I} + \color{red}{2}\rho''\Delta\mathbf{z} (\Delta\mathbf{z})^T)\mathbf{J}
$$
Can please someone help me to see where I am doing the wrong step?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was reading the same paper today. If you look at equation (3), the objective function is actually
$$\frac{1}{2}\rho(\mathbf{z}(\mathbf{x})^T \mathbf{z}(\mathbf{x})),$$
not what you stated at first
$$\rho(\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{z}(\mathbf{x})^T \mathbf{z}(\mathbf{x})).$$
Then $\left(\frac{\partial \mathbf{z}(\mathbf{x})^T \mathbf{z}(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\right)^2$ will generate a coefficient $2^2=4$ at your second term.
So nothing in your derivation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at A.129 and A.158 of my [thesis](https://eprints.qut.edu.au/209881/1/Chanoh_Park_Thesis.pdf). This was my conclusion after reading multiple articles on the approximation method but I can't find the source articles.

Comment: Thanks! (and congrats for the thesis :)) But is the *robustified* version of the Gauss Newton approach addressed in it? I've seen that you have addressed the Gauss Newton method at the equations you've mentioned, but I couldn't find the robust modification introduced by Triggs et. al.

Comment: Now I got it. So, you are trying to estimate H from M-estimator. A.9.4 is related to that but not the same. I always treated them separately but in not the combined way. This is an interesting problem.

Comment: I will try this later and let you know

Comment: Yes that's my doubt, thanks a lot. Btw, treating them separately seems an interesting new thing to learn :) Do you recommend any source specifically that explains this?

Comment: I remember there was a really good tutorial. I will check my old HDD and let you know

Comment: That's great, thanks :)